# Threading question

Tags: python, tkinter

so i have the code :

```
from Tkinter import *
from urllib2 import *
import thread
Admin = Tk()
def download():
    def dwnload():
        def Listen():
                os.startfile(filepath)

        chunks = 100000
        dat = ''
        runum = runums.replace(' ', '%20')
        song = '3 rounds and a sound'
        url = 'http://bonton.sweetdarkness.net/music/Blind%20Pilot%20--%203%20Rounds%20and%20A%20Sound.mp3'
        down = urlopen(url)
        downso = 0
        tota = down.info().getheader('Content-Length').strip()
        tota = int(tota)
        while 1:
            a = down.read(chunks)
            downso += len(a)

            if not a:
                break
            dat += a
            percent = float(downso) / tota
            percent = round(percent*100, 1)

            sys.stdout.write(str(percent))
            sys.stdout.flush()

            sys.stdout.write("\b"*4)


        filepath = 'C:\\WhaleWire\\Downloaded\\' + song + '.mp3'

        local = open(filepath, "wb")
        local.write(dat)
        print '1Done'
    thread.start_new_thread(dwnload, ())
button = Button(Admin, text='Download', command=download)
button.pack()
button = Button(Admin, text='Download', command=download)
button.pack()
Admin.mainloop()
```

When i press either of of the download buttons i get a error: `Unhandled exception in thread started by <function dwnload at 0x00000000029D4C88>`

Comment: Are there any details about the unhandled exception?

Comment: no thats the only detailes ive goten in the error.

Comment: Are you sure it's a threading problem? What happens if you call that `dwnload()` function without threading?

Comment: Ya it wasn't the dwload() function. switching to mtTkinter seemed to fix my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thread is a low-level interface to threads, I would suggest using [threading](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html), which actually has meaningful exceptions. And, make sure there is absolutely no convergence between Tkinter and your second thread, because locking is a very, very, painful thing.

I thing you may need locking in the `download` function.